# Unity UI elements stop drawing after some time

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I have strange situation.

**** UPDATE ****

After more investigating in this situation I realized that objects not disappear but are not drawn after SetActive(true).

This only affects objects on UI layer, all other objects are fain.

This objects on UI are not visible but they works (like buttons etc.)

No GC problems or memory leaks :/

This also happens on Android, I can't reproduce this on Player.

---

My game have a long play time, a sometimes objects that have .SetActive(true) / false changed  disappearing.

This looks like SetActive(true) can't be set and object disappear, but other objects where SetActive isn't changed works well.

I can't find why it's happen. I can't connect also profiler because this is android game and I can't connect it to the same wifi as profiler.

On the editor player with profiler I don't see any memory leaks, only small GC allocated like 4-7kb and cleared to 1kb after time.

Is it possible that such situation can be the result of memory leak?

This also happens only sometimes and I can reproduce it to find the reason.

Maybe anyone have similar situation and can give me some idea?

After suggest GC I checked and it shows stady 2mb:

(int)System.GC.GetTotalMemory (false) / 1000000F

Comment: almost certainly, it is not related to a memory leak.

Comment: This would be (possibly) a GC issue, not memory leak. Memory leak would be if it wasn't returning memory that it should.

Comment: I will try to check this by using some onGui method like this: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/AllocationStats  Or do you have any other idea?

Comment: GC.GetTotalMemory shows steady 2mb. so I think it's not the reason

Comment: What unity version and how many canvas do you have active at thesame time?

Comment: I have 7 objects that have Canvas and Canvas scaler. Each of these objects have also 5-7 child objects like buttons. Unity 5.3.2f1

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but it was the problem I had last year and I don't know if it is fixed now. Can you make sure that Only 1 Canvas is enabled in the game at a time. If canvas A is Enabled, Canvas B and others must be Disabled...

Comment: I just found that in one script in Update I have function that can several times SetActive(true) to object that is already active. In long time that can be the reason?

Comment: well try commenting it and see what happens... Although make sure that only 1 Canvas is enabled in the game at a time. There was a bug about this and I dont know if it is fixed.

Comment: Now I have only 1 Canvas enabled but this happens again. I think that this is bug with too many changes in setActive for UI objects. I will test it with changing alpha instead setActive to be sure that this is a problem. After this I will send it as a bug.